# Changing letter typed by Keyboard by other letter and show it in UITextfield

Tags: ios

I want to know if possible, to change the letter typed by keyboard before to display in a UITexfield (To create a secret code) and then in other UITextfield decodify it.

i. e.

I type " a " and then UITextfield Will display "d" and other UITexfield  to read  and invert "d" to " a"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use method – textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: in UITextFieldDelegate.

f.e.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
NSString* encodedString = [self encode:string];
textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:
        encodedString];
self.decodedTextField.text = [self.decodedTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
return NO;                  
}
```

it is just example, you should implement replacement more careful.

Comment: Ok, this is to change to code and How  I do to reverse to decode "d" To "a" ?

Comment: textField2.text = [self decode:textFiled1.text], is it what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want in the second texfield return the letter previously typed of "d" to "a"

Comment: I tried and works, but exist a method which I can take this letter  "a" and   back the next letter three position count forward? i. e.  (a,b,c,) ->" d"